# How to rebuild fakeAsync into async function prooperly

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a code that work perfect in test fakeAsync but doesn't work when I use async.

comp.loginStatus is return in constructor:

```
this.subscriptionStatus = this.userService.getStatus().subscribe(status => {
  this.loginStatus = status;
});
```

In test fakeAsync work:

```
fit('user inser wrong data - server response 401', fakeAsync(() => {
  expect(comp.loginStatus).toBe(null);
  let object = {
    "timestamp" : 1501857773994,
    "status" : 401,
    "error" : "Unauthorized",
    "exception" : "org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException",
    "message" : "Unauthorized",
    "path" : "/auth"
  };
  let spy = spyOn(userService, 'login').and.returnValue(Promise.reject(object));

  comp.loginAction();
  tick();

  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(comp.loginStatus).toBe(401);
}));
```

But async way doesn't work:

```
fit('user inser wrong data - server response 401', async(() => {
  expect(comp.loginStatus).toBe(null);
  console.log(comp.registerStatus);
  let object = {
    "timestamp" : 1501857773994,
    "status" : 401,
    "error" : "Unauthorized",
    "exception" : "org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException",
    "message" : "Unauthorized",
    "path" : "/auth"
  };
  let spy = spyOn(userService, 'login').and.returnValue(Promise.reject(object));

  comp.loginAction();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(comp.loginStatus).toBe(401);
  });
}));
```

Comment: `async` identifier is outside of immediately invoked function

Comment: why do you need that? fakeAsync works works with zone, `async` doesnt

Comment: @Maximus - i doesn't found this information on Angular.io page. According with docs `async` and `fakeAsync` running the test body in a special `fakeAsync`/`async` test zone and docs doesn't write anything about different test zone for both.

Comment: @guest271314 can you tell more? Where is my fault?

Comment: Have not tried `jasmine`. If you are trying to create an immediately invoked arrow function `async` should be within the expression `(async()={})()`. Though it appears that you are trying to pass a function reference which will be called, not a function which is immediately invoked. Why do you try to use `async` though `await` is not used within function?

Comment: I try to use it in accordance with docs: https://angular.io/guide/testing#the-async-function-in-it  where async is used in the same way as I used it.

Comment: @kris_IV Not familiar with angular tests. Can you describe "doesn't work"? Have you considered filing an issue at https://github.com/angular/angular.js?